# excel export just displays values instead of downloading in codeigniter php (without any pluggin)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i  need to download as excel sheet without using any pluggin in codeigniter php but my code only displays values.
Here is my code-

```
$filename = 'tasks_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("Content-Type: text/csv; ");
$file = fopen('php://output');
$header = array("Username","Name","Gender","Email");
fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){ 
fputcsv($file,$line); 
}
fclose($file);
```

i get result as Username,Name,Gender,Email  instead of download.

Comment: csv or excel? they are not the same thing,

Comment: i am trying to do csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header = array("Username","Name","Gender","Email");
fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){ 
fputcsv($file,$line); 
}
fclose($file);
exit;
```

In your code, the mode is missing in fopen(). It is the type of access you require to the file. Try this snippet

Comment: i tried with application/csv  as content type still there is issue.

Comment: You need to modify $file = fopen('php://output', 'w'); Your code does not specify the mode, if you want to write to a file you need to specify 'w'

Comment: i have copy the code, still there is issue now i have my code as 
   $filename = 'tasks_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $header = array("Username","Name","Gender","Email");
    fputcsv($file, $header);
    foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){ 
    fputcsv($file,$line); 
    }
    fclose($file);
    exit;

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, working for me

```
$filename = 'tasks_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("Content-Type: text/csv; ");
$file = fopen('php://output','w');
$header = array("Username","Name","Gender","Email");
fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){ 
fputcsv($file,$line); 
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$filename = 'tasks_'.date('Ymd').'.csv'; 
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$record = array("Username","Name","Gender","Email");

fputcsv($output, $record);

foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){
$rec =array($line['Username'],$line['Name'],$line['Gender'],$line['Email']);
        fputcsv($output, $rec);
    }
fclose($output);
```